# Surface integral over an arbitrary triangle in 3D

Tags: vector-analysis

I have a triangular surface given in 3D with nodes $$[x_1,y_1,z_1]^T, [x_2,y_2,z_2]^T,[x_3,y_3,z_3]^T$$
I want to calculate the surface integral of a function 
$$\oint_s \vec{f}(x,y,z)\bullet d\vec{S}$$
How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

One way how to do it is to parametrize the points of a triangle as
$$\vec P=\vec P_1+(\vec P_2-\vec P_1)u+(\vec P_3-\vec P_1)v.$$
I assume the orientation of triangle is consistent with numeration of vertices $123$. The normal $d\vec S$ is constant and can be found using vector product:
$$
d\vec{S} = \partial_u\vec P\times\partial_v\vec P = (\vec P_2-\vec P_1)\times(\vec P_3-\vec P_1)\,du\,dv = \vec n\,du\,dv
$$

So the integral can be found as:
$$
\int_S\vec f(x,y,z)\cdot d\vec S = \int_0^1\int_0^{1-u} \vec n\cdot \vec f\Big(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v)\Big)du\,dv,
$$
where functions $x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v)$ are the coordinates of $\vec P(u,v)$

Comment: So if i understand correctly, we are mapping the triangle to anoher triangle with vertices on points (1,0,0), (0,1,0) and (0,0,0). Do I change the normal outward from the surface to be the normal outward from this new triangle or I keep the orientation of the normal the same?

Comment: You can think of it this way. However, we calculated the normal directly, so from the perspective of double integral the integral function is scalar

Comment: What i means was, should i find the normal of the unmapped surface or the mapped surface?

Comment: I have written the formula for you. $\vec n=(\vec P_2-\vec P_1)\times(\vec P_3-\vec P_1) $